# Chrome issue with hovering over links that overlay Youtube embed

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

Ok, this is a bit tough to explain.  I've created tabs.  On the first tab is a YouTube embed.  If you click on the 2nd, 3rd, etc tab, you successfully see the tab content.  But, if you hover over any links found in this content, the Youtube embed appears though the hovered over link.  Only happening in Chrome.  I've found similar topics but couldn't figure out if they were exactly the same issue I'm having.

Reproduce:

http://gville.biz/biz/76
Let the page fully load, inluding YouTube video.
Click on Custom Tab or Facebook Tab.
Hover over the links... if they are aligned over the youtube video (underneath), the youtube video is visible though the link.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed by either the latest version of Chrome or Flash somehow... it is still doing this on one of my computers, but not the other... So I think it may be because I updated Flash on the computer that is fixed..

Answer (score -1):

Solution found by OP:

> This seems to have been fixed by either the latest version of Chrome or Flash somehow... it is still doing this on one of my computers, but not the other... So I think it may be because I updated Flash on the computer that is fixed..